# Dropdown doesn't appear

Tags: html, css

I am confused why my drop-down cannot appear. Could anyone possibly know the issue? Help is appreciated!

I've checked my drop-down with displaying it and it can, but I can't set the drop-down to show up whenever the mouse is hovering on a link. This is my code:

```css
body {
  font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.ic {
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-right: 5px;
  font-size: .9rem;
}

.wrap {
  background-color: black;
}

#topbar {
  padding: 0;
  width: 1200px;
  /* FOR a static width like Posh CSS */
  height: 50px;
  margin: auto;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: .8rem;
}

.nospace {
  color: white;
}

li {
  margin: 15px;
}

li.left {
  float: left;
  list-style: none;
}

li.right {
  float: right;
  list-style: none;
}

li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: aqua;
}

#banner {
  background: url(bg1.jpg) no-repeat center;
  height: 600px;
  background-size: 1650px;
  opacity: 0.7;
  font-family: 'Forum', cursive;
  font-size: 20px;
}

ul li {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.menubar {
  width: 1200px;
  margin: auto;
  display: block;
}

.menubar a {
  padding: 10px;
  color: black;
}

.menubar a:hover {
  background-color: white;
}

.drop-nav {
  position: relative;
}

.drop-nav:after {
  content: "\25BC";
  font-size: .5em;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 40%;
  right: 1%;
}

#content {
  padding: 0;
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
  background-color: gray;
  min-width: 120px;
  z-index: 1;
}

#content a {
  color: blue;
  border-bottom: 2px solid black;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}

#content a:hover {
  background-color: aqua;
}

li .drop-nav a:hover {
  display: block;
}

.wrap01 {
  height: 60px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid gray;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="Halaman">
    <div class="wrap">
      <div id="topbar">
        <div class="nospace">
          <li class="left"><span class="ic">&#9743;</span> +00 (123) 456 7890</li>
          <li class="left"><span class="ic">&#9993;</span> info@domain.com</li>
          <li class="right"><a href="#">Tentang</a></li>
          <li class="right"><a href="#">Kontak</a></li>
          <li class="right"><a href="#">Login</a></li>
          <li class="right"><a href="#">Register</a></li>
          <li class="right"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-home"></i></a></li>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="banner">
      <div class="wrap01">
        <nav class="menubar">
          <li class="left">Sistem Pemberkasan Gudang</li>
          <li class="right"><a href="#">Link Text</a></li>
          <li class="right"><a href="#">Link Text</a></li>
          <li class="right"><a class="drop-nav" href="#">Dropdown</a>
            <ul id="content">
              <a href="#">zero 1</a>
              <a href="#">zero 1</a>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li class="right"><a class="drop-nav" href="#">Halaman</a></li>
          <li class="right"><a href="index.html" style="color: red;">Rumah</a></li>
        </nav>
      </div>
</body>
```

I have done some research on the internet and W3C but still can't find the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the wrong selector at `li .drop-nav a:hover`

You need to set the `#content` to display again. Using `display: none` will prevent you from using transition, so I used `visibility` & `height` attribute.

You can check below.

```css
body {
  font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.ic {
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-right: 5px;
  font-size: .9rem;
}

.wrap {
  background-color: black;
}

#topbar {
  padding: 0;
  width: 1200px;
  /* FOR a static width like Posh CSS */
  height: 50px;
  margin: auto;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: .8rem;
}

.nospace {
  color: white;
}

li {
  margin: 15px;
}

li.left {
  float: left;
  list-style: none;
}

li.right {
  float: right;
  list-style: none;
}

li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: aqua;
}

#banner {
  background: url(bg1.jpg) no-repeat center;
  height: 600px;
  background-size: 1650px;
  opacity: 0.7;
  font-family: 'Forum', cursive;
  font-size: 20px;
}

ul li {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  position: relative;
}

nav li {
  position: relative;
}

.menubar {
  width: 1200px;
  margin: auto;
  display: block;
}

.menubar a {
  padding: 10px;
  color: black;
}

.menubar a:hover {
  background-color: white;
}

.drop-nav {
  position: relative;
}

.drop-nav:after {
  content: "\25BC";
  font-size: .5em;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 40%;
  right: 1%;
}

#content {
  padding: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  height: 0px;
  background-color: gray;
  z-index: 1;
}

#content a {
  color: blue;
  border-bottom: 2px solid black;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}

#content a:hover {
  background-color: aqua;
}

li:hover ul#content {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 25px;
  left: 0px;
  height: 200px;
  width: 120px;
  visibility: visible;
}

.wrap01 {
  height: 60px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid gray;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="Halaman">
    <div class="wrap">
      <div id="topbar">
        <div class="nospace">
          <li class="left"><span class="ic">&#9743;</span> +00 (123) 456 7890</li>
          <li class="left"><span class="ic">&#9993;</span> info@domain.com</li>
          <li class="right"><a href="#">Tentang</a></li>
          <li class="right"><a href="#">Kontak</a></li>
          <li class="right"><a href="#">Login</a></li>
          <li class="right"><a href="#">Register</a></li>
          <li class="right"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-home"></i></a></li>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="banner">
      <div class="wrap01">
        <nav class="menubar">
          <li class="left">Sistem Pemberkasan Gudang</li>
          <li class="right"><a href="#">Link Text</a></li>
          <li class="right"><a href="#">Link Text</a></li>
          <li class="right"><a class="drop-nav" href="#">Dropdown</a>
            <ul id="content">
              <a href="#">zero 1</a>
              <a href="#">zero 1</a>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li class="right"><a class="drop-nav" href="#">Halaman</a></li>
          <li class="right"><a href="index.html" style="color: red;">Rumah</a></li>
        </nav>
      </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Great it really works, so the problem was the transition and my selector. big thanks for the answer you are great people ;). thsi issue has make me stress for 1 night bro

Comment: Please mark it as answer if you resolved your problem.
Besides, it's not only selector. You need to specify the position of your drop down for it to display correctly below your `Dropdown` main menu item.
`li:hover ul#content {
...
  position: absolute;
  top: 25px;
  left: 0px;
...
}
`

Answer (score 0):

What you `display:none` is `#content` so in your css when you hover it should be

`li .drop-nav a:hover #content{
  display: block;
}`

Comment: ive tried it but still none change, really appreciat for your help. it solve with the first answer