# How to make ul button text fade in and out when button is clicked?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Quick question, how can I make my Ul buttons slowly appear (when menu button is clicked) using Javascript. Here is what I have so far:

Basically, when the menu expand nav function is called I want the li tags to slowly appear/disappear. How can I go about this? This is only a snippet of my script because it is quite a lot.

Thanks!

```js
setup();

function setup() {
  document.getElementById("extend-nav-container").style.display = "none";
}

function expandNav() {
  if (document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].style.overflow === "hidden") {
    document.getElementById("extend-nav").style.height = "0px";
    document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].style.overflow = "";
    document.getElementById("extend-nav-container").style.display = "none";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("extend-nav").style.height = "100vh";
    document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].style.overflow = "hidden";
    document.getElementById("extend-nav-container").style.display = "";
    document.getElementById('fadeout').style.opacity = '0';
  }
}

function myFunction(x) {
  document.getElementById("extend-nav").style.height = "0px";
  document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].style.overflow = "";
  document.getElementById("extend-nav-container").style.display = "none";
}

var x = window.matchMedia("(max-width: 768px)")
myFunction(x);
x.addListener(myFunction);
```

```css
.new-nav {
  background: black;
  display: flex;
  transition: 0.5s;
  justify-content: center;
}

.new-nav .container {
  width: 98%;
  height: 98%;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

#extend-nav ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  height: 100%;
  transition: 1s;
}

#extend-nav li {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

#extend-nav a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  font-weight: lighter;
  transition: 0.5s;
}
```

```html
<div class="new-nav" id="extend-nav">
  <div class="container" id="extend-nav-container">
    <ul id="second-nav-ul">
      <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Ban</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Warn</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Gift</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Records</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Moderator</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">News</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Edit</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Account</i></a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Sign Out</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You can check out this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51183123/dropdown-doesnt-appear/51183263#51183263 
It's the same problem as `display: none` cannot be used in transition

Comment: @ToanLu But how would I actually add the transition effect to the text when the function is called?

Comment: Do you wish to do it in vanilla JS or are you comfortable in using the Jquery library?

Comment: @KaranDhir I'd prefer in vanilla JS. I'm not comfortable using Jquery library yet.

Comment: I think Toan's answer should work for you. But if you need some additional features and really wish to dig deeper, visit: https://gomakethings.com/controlling-the-transition-timing-of-show-and-hide-methods-with-vanilla-javascript/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use javascript to toggle a class when user click on your hamburger or somewhere on the menu.

`Display: none` cannot be applied with transition effect, so you need to use `visibility` attribute instead.

```js
function myFunction() {
    var element = document.getElementById("second-nav-ul");
    element.classList.toggle("collapse");
}
```

```css
.nav {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 10px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  background-color: #000;  
  height: 50px;
}

ul li a {
  color: #FFF;
}

.collapse {
  height: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  visibility: hidden;
  transition:all 0.1s linear;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="new-nav" id="extend-nav">
  <button onclick="myFunction()">Toggle Me</button>
  <div class="container" id="extend-nav-container">
    <ul id="second-nav-ul" class="nav">
      <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Ban</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Warn</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Gift</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Records</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Moderator</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">News</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Edit</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Account</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Sign Out</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you! But may I ask what element.classList.toggle("collapse"); does?

Comment: It like you switching on/off a class. If the element does not have this class then it will add the class, vice versa

Comment: Ohh, okay. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 1):

try with this

```
#extend-nav{
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s;
  -o-transition: all 0.5s; }
```

Comment: Thank you! This semi-fixed my problem :)